# function reverse_substrings that takes as input a string elements and reverses the order of its substrings in python

Tags: python

I have a function that reverses the elements of an str list :
input : '2076,3B,19C,138D'
the output must be : '138D,19C,3B,2076'
i made this code :

```
def remove_null(cat_string):
    # todo exercise 1
    result = cat_string[::-1]
    return result
```

but I get this :
D831,C91,B3,6702

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function reverses the string by character.
You want to reverse the order of the elements delimited by comma:

```py
cat_string = cat_string.split(',')
cat_string.reverse()
cat_string = ','.join(cat_string)
```

or one-liner:

```py
cat_string = ','.join(reversed(cat_string.split(',')))
```